# Retry Task Framework

Tags: java

I have a number of situations where I need to retry a task n-times if it fails (sometimes with some form of back-off-before-retry logic). Generally, if an exception is thrown, the task should be retried up to the max-retry count.

I can easily write something to do this fairly generically, but not wanting to re-invent the wheel I was wondering if anyone can recommend any frameworks for this. The only thing I have been able to find is: [Ant Retry](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/retry.html) but I don't want to use Ant tasks directly in my application.

Thanks

Comment: what kind of task you want retry?

Comment: @fatih - It doesn't matter, retrying a task is an abstract concept.

Comment: Interestingly, everyone seems to wrap the action to retry in some class that does the retry, which requires the action to be retried to conform to some interface. I would rather implement a backoff/retry strategy manager with just one method `boolean shallWeRetryOnceMore()`, when called it either immediately returns `false` or waits for a time, depending on backoff algorithm, and then returns true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `RetriableTasks` as outlined in this post: [Retrying Operations in Java](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/08/retrying-operations-in-java.html). You can quite easily change its waiting algorithm if you like.

Sample code:

```
//creates a task which will retry 3 times with an interval of 5 seconds
RetriableTask r = new RetriableTask(3, 5000, new Callable(){
    public Object call() throws Exception{
        //put your code here
    }
});
r.call();
```

Comment: This answer is really old. Failsafe seems to be a really good option for what the OP wants.

Comment: @AnkitSultana - Old is not necessarily bad. Do you see any problems in the above approach ?

Answer (score 18):

Check out [Failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) (which I authored). It's a simple, zero-dependency library for performing retries, and supports synchronous and asynchronous retries, Java 8 integration, event listeners, integration with other async APIs, etc:

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy()
  .handle(ConnectException.class, SocketException.class);
  .withMaxRetries(3);

Connection connection = Failsafe.with(retryPolicy).get(() -> connect());
```

Doesn't get much easier.

Comment: Can I use FailSafe to keep retrying until a "condition" is met ? I want to keep making an api call until certain conditions are met or until a few tries. Examples of conditions - response code should be correct, OR response code should be correct and response should contain certain things etc.

Comment: @MasterJoe You can use handleIfResult method.

Answer (score 9):

If you use Spring:

```
//import the necessary classes
import org.springframework.batch.retry.RetryCallback;
import org.springframework.batch.retry.RetryContext;
import org.springframework.batch.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy;
import org.springframework.batch.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy;
import org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate;
...

// create the retry template
final RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
template.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(5));
final ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000L);
template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

// execute the operation using the retry template
template.execute(new RetryCallback<Remote>() {
  @Override
  public Remote doWithRetry(final RetryContext context) throws Exception {
    return (Remote) Naming.lookup("rmi://somehost:2106/MyApp");
  }
});
```

[Original blog post](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/retrying-operations-using-springs.html)

Comment: More specifically, if you use, and want a dependency on, Spring Batch.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Spring**, it is **very simple** using [Spring Retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) Library.

Now, Spring Retry is an individual library (**earlier** it was part of **Spring Batch**) framework.

**Step1:** Add spring retry dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step2:** Add `@EnableRetry` annotation to your class which contains main() method of your application **or** into any of your `@Configuration` class .

**Step3:** Add `@Retryable` annotation to your **method** which you want to retry/call again, in case of exceptions.

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=5,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
public void retrySomething() throws Exception{
    logger.info("printSomething{} is called");
    throw new SQLException();
}
```

This `@Retryable` annotation will retry/call `retrySomething()` 5 times (**including** the 1st failure).

Current thread will wait for 3000 ms or **3 seconds** between next retry.

Comment: What do you think about the FailSafe library ?

Comment: Can it be used to do something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582706/how-to-retry-a-function-call-with-java

Answer (score 3):

I have one answer already, but it was three years ago and I have to add that now I absolutley love [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) project. Let me just show you the code.

```
Callable<Boolean> callable = new Callable<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return true; // do something useful here
    }
};

Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder()
        .retryIfResult(Predicates.<Boolean>isNull())
        .retryIfExceptionOfType(IOException.class)
        .retryIfRuntimeException()
        .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.stopAfterAttempt(3))
        .build();
try {
    retryer.call(callable);
} catch (RetryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Of course Guava is a dependency: https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying/blob/master/build.gradle#L84 Otherwise your code example wouldn't compile.

Comment: This is neat and StopStrategies abstraction is cool. Tho, I am unclear whether this works well (or at all) for implementing different retry strategies like a regular cadence retry at a fixed time interval, or exponential back-off, or staggered.

Comment: @mulya - The last commit was in may 2016. Either no one is maintaining that project anymore or the project does not need any maintenance at all. So, that is a concern for me. Btw, what do you think about the FailSafe library ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 No maintenance is sad, you right. If you need something bulletproof you can try hystrix or resilience4j. Never hear of FailSafe actually

Answer (score 1):

One option to factor this out of your codebase is to use the command pattern between the components of your application.
Once you turn a call to a business method into an object, you can hand around the call easily and have an abstract RetryHandler that takes a command and retries it. This should be independent from the actual call and reusable.

Comment: Thanks Jochen, this is broadly what I have since the tasks are either Runnable or Callable instances anyway. I was just hoping their might be a framework that provided options such as specifying different types of retry logic and back-off algorithms...

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. Which is quite unusual, I'd agree. We use retries mostly to deal with optimistic exceptions when talking to the persistence layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a pretty flexible retry utility [here](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/base/Callables.java)

You can retry any Callable with:

```
public static <T> T executeWithRetry(final Callable<T> what, final int nrImmediateRetries,
        final int nrTotalRetries, final int retryWaitMillis, final int timeoutMillis,
        final Predicate<? super T> retryOnReturnVal, final Predicate<Exception> retryOnException)
```

with immediate + delayed retries, with a max timeout, and retry either on decisions based on result or exception.

There are several other versions of this function with more or less flexibility.

I have written also a aspect that can be applied with annotations [Retry](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-aspects/src/main/java/org/spf4j/annotations/Retry.java) [Retry Aspect](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-aspects/src/main/java/org/spf4j/aspects/RetryAspect.java)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).  Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408858/quartz-retry-when-failure) Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: This is not a useful general purpose solution for retrying. It is specifically about retrying failed quartz jobs.