# How to retry a function call with Java?

Tags: java

I am using a custom Java library to make REST API calls. I have functions which make api calls using that library. I want to be able to retry some api calls/functions, but the library does not provide that functionality.

I'd like to retry an api call n times, OR for a certain amount of time, pausing x seconds between every execution. In all cases, the api call should be retried only until certain conditions are met, for example the Response (class) object response code == 200 and response body contains "successful !!!". I also want to be able to ignore certain exceptions while making these calls.

Pseudocode for what I need :

```
    SuperLibrary superLibrary = new SuperLibrary();
    superLibrary.do(myApiCallFunction()).
              .handle(ConnectException.class)
              .withDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
              //.withMaxTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))//Also an option
              .withMaxRetries(3)
              .until(Some Conditions are true);
```

Is there any reliable and "simple" java library which allows me to do this ? I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to any code examples which do what I need.

Thanks !

Comment: If you're not already doing so, it sounds like you might want to consider using a framework like Spring Boot: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-spring-retry

Comment: My "general" recommendation is to look at `Future`s and any possible "promises" API for Java

Comment: @paulsm4 - Will SpringRetry bring in too many unnecessary dependencies of the Spring Framework or just the code that helps with retry ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer -  could you please point me to a code example ?

Comment: [java promises](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+promises&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: [Java 8: Writing asynchronous code with CompletableFuture](https://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/)

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Spring retry will suit your needs, throw exception when REST calls returns failure (other than 200).

Answer (score 2):

I use function in java8 and write a RetryHelp to do this

```
package com.river.reytry;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

/**
 * @author riverfan
 * @date 2019-07-19
 */
public class RetryHelp {
    private int num = 1;
    private Supplier<Boolean> consumer;
    private long intervalTime = 0;
    private Supplier<RuntimeException> exceptionSupplier;

    public static RetryHelp build() {
        return new RetryHelp();
    }

    public RetryHelp tryWith(Supplier<Boolean> t) {
        this.consumer = t;
        return this;
    }

    public RetryHelp tryInterval(long time) {
        intervalTime = time;
        return this;
    }

    public RetryHelp tryNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        return this;
    }

    public RetryHelp elseThrow(Supplier<RuntimeException> exceptionSupplier) {
        this.exceptionSupplier = exceptionSupplier;
        return this;
    }

    public void start() throws RuntimeException {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            if (consumer.get()) {
                return;
            }
            //最后一次不用sleep
            if(i == num-1){
                continue;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(intervalTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("no success throw exception");
        if(exceptionSupplier == null){
            return;
        }
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }


}
```

and the test is like this

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;

public class RetryHelpTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("--------------");
            RetryHelp.build()
                    .tryWith(() -> {
                        System.out.println("hello world");
                        return RandomUtils.nextBoolean();
                    })
                    .tryInterval(1L)
                    .tryNum(3)
                    .elseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("some thing wrong"))
                    .start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more elegant way of achieving what mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can meet your objective without needing a library.

```
       SuperLibrary superLibrary = new SuperLibrary();
       int maxRetries = 3;
       boolean someCondition = true;
       int attempt = 1;
       do {
           try {
               Response response = superLibrary.do(myApiCallFunction());
               if((response.getResponseCode() == 200 && response.getResponseText().contains("successful !!!")) ||
                       attempt == maxRetries) {
                   //success
                   someCondition = false;
               }
           }
           catch(ConnectException ce) {
               //Sleep for 3 seconds
               Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(3).toMillis());
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
               //Ignore other exception
           }
           attempt++;
       }
       while(someCondition);
```

It's probably not super elegant or succinct. But it is simple. You can build a separate wrapper class or your own library to hide this complexity from your primary class.

Comment: You should do some research into `CompletableFuture`, not sure if it supports retry directly, but will take care just about the rest ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Point taken. `CompletabeFuture` with JDK9 might make this more elegant.

Comment: I've never seen it before, but it might be worth taking the time to look into ... or not ;)