# Quartz job can not be executed in Spring cron

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jobs, stateful, quartz

The similar questions seem to be asked many times,but I still can't find the exact answer.I use org.quartz.StatefulJob to setup a scheduled job to retry it for 5 times by simulating an Exception and Spring cron to trigger it, but some exception occurred,here's the details:

```
@Service(value = "cronJobRetryImpl")
public class DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest implements StatefulJob {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws 
JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("enter execute ...");
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        long count = 
            NumberUtils.toLong(String.valueOf(dataMap.get("count")));

        if (count >= 5) {
            logger.info("Retries exceeded...");
            JobExecutionException e = new JobExecutionException("Retries 
                exceeded");
            e.setUnscheduleAllTriggers(true);
            throw e;
        }

        try {
            logger.info("business begin...");
            dataMap.put("count", 0);
            int n = 10 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            count++;
            dataMap.putAsString("count", count);
            JobExecutionException e2 = new JobExecutionException(e);
            try {
                logger.info("Thread begin to sleep for 3 seconds...");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                logger.info("interrupted exception",e1);
            }
            e2.refireImmediately();
            logger.info("job refired ...");
            throw e2;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the Spring xml:

```
<!-- retry test start -->
<bean id="cronJobRetryImplTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="cronJobRetryImpl" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>execute</value>
    </property>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="cronJobRetryTime" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <ref bean="cronJobRetryImplTask" />
    </property>
    <property name="cronExpression">
        <value>20 30 9 * * ?</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- retry test end -->
<bean id="startQuertz" lazy-init="false" autowire="no"     
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronJobRetryTime" />
        </list>
    </property>
```

I planned to trigger it on every 9:30:20AM,and the result:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cronJobRetryTime' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-job.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cronJobRetryImplTask' while setting bean property 'jobDetail'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cronJobRetryImplTask' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-job.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tv.huan.cms.services.rest.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.execute()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cronJobRetryImplTask' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-job.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tv.huan.cms.services.rest.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.execute()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tv.huan.cms.services.rest.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.execute()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:178)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 31 more
```

-----------------------first edit---------------------------

Yes,yes,samabcde's replay is effective and thanks samabcde for your patience and effort,but problems seem to be in the code itself.I try to run these codes but the job can not be executed again when the simulated exception occurred:

```
INFO  2018-11-02 14:43:00,022 [DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.java,16] - enter 
execute ...
INFO  2018-11-02 14:43:00,027 [DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.java,28] - 
business begin...
INFO  2018-11-02 14:43:00,027 [DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.java,36] - 
Thread begin to sleep for 3 seconds...
INFO  2018-11-02 14:43:03,028 [DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.java,42] - job 
refired ...
INFO  2018-11-02 14:43:03,031 [JobRunShell.java,221] - Job 
DEFAULT.cronJobRetryImplTask threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero 
[See nested exception: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero]
   at tv.huan.cms.services.rest.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.execute(DuMiSynchronizati onRetryRest.java:34)
   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
   Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
   at tv.huan.cms.services.rest.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.execute(DuMiSynchronizat
 ionRetryRest.java:30)
   ... 2 more
```

the log showed up an exception and no more clue.How can I achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Spring Quartz BeanCreationException problem

From the Spring xml

```
<bean id="cronJobRetryImplTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="cronJobRetryImpl" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>execute</value>
    </property>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

The arguments of [MethodInvoker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MethodInvoker.html)(`MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` extend) is not specified, hence it assumes there is no argument. As a result the exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cronJobRetryImplTask' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-job.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tv.huan.cms.services.rest.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest.**execute()**

is thrown as there is no method `execute` without arguments in `DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest` class.

To resolve the problem,  `JobDetailFactoryBean` should be used instead of `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` as said in the [Java Doc of MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.html)

> **Avoids the need for implementing a one-line Quartz Job** that just invokes an existing service method on a Spring-managed target bean.

However, `DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest` is implemented as a Quartz Job, and using `execute` method of Job, which requires `JobExecutionContext`. In this case, `JobDetailFactoryBean` should be the appropriate factory bean. To change the factory bean, just update the bean definition of **cronJobRetryImplTask** as

```
<bean id="cronJobRetryImplTask"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="jobClass">
        <value>gov.housingauthority.pass.app.DuMiSynchronizationRetryRest
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Since `cronJobRetryImpl` bean is not needed after the change the `@Service` annotation of 
can be removed also.

Finally, since `StatefulJob` is deprecated, as suggested in the [Java Doc of StatefulJob](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html),

> use DisallowConcurrentExecution and/or PersistJobDataAfterExecution
>   annotations instead.

### Job Not Retry Immediately problem

For the problem that the job does not retry immediately, this is due to using 
`e2.refireImmediately();`, which is a getter only.To set the refire flag:

For quartz on or before version 1.5.2,
we can use `new JobExecutionException(e, true)` where the second parameter will set the `refireImmediately` as true.

After version 1.7.2, setter method `setRefireImmediately(boolean refireImmediately);` is provided.

Comment: @Eric Ben, please try to change `e2.refireImmediately();` to `e2.setRefireImmediately(true);` as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408858/quartz-retry-when-failure)

Comment: Yes,I have read that question and the key is the version of my quartz.jar,at the beginning I use an older one(1.5.2) and it could not support the method with a boolean parameter ,so I changed it to a no-parameter method with the same name.After your comments I changed the jar file to a newer version(1.8.6), and there is an overload method ,so all goes well now.Thanks again.