# Using custom executor with quartz scheduling library

Tags: java-8, quartz-scheduler, executorservice

I am using quartz library, mainly to schedule multiple tasks that will run forever at specific time. I have a customized executor (a retry executor that reschedule a task for a specified number of times in case of failure (retries are customizable). I want to know if there is a way to setup quartz to use this customized executor? Currently I am using the executor inside the `Job` i.e. call `executor.execute()` inside the Job's execute method.

Answer (score 1):

From the Guide there is only explained how to [configure your own ThreadPool](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/configuration.html#configuration-of-threadpool-tune-resources-for-job-execution).

#### Fine-tuning the Scheduler

You can also implement Quatz's interface [`ThreadExecutor`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/org/quartz/spi/ThreadExecutor.html) or adjust your "RetryExecutor" implementation to do so.

Then it can be passed as component via [`setThreadExecutor`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/org/quartz/core/QuartzSchedulerResources.html#setThreadExecutor-org.quartz.spi.ThreadExecutor-) to the `QuartzSchedulerResources` which in turn are used to configure [`QuartzScheduler`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html) - the heart of Quartz.

#### Keep the Job isolated

It's discouraged to modify scheduling or execute additional jobs from within a job's execute method. This control-flow is kept outside from the jobs by Quartz. It's part of the Scheduler's responsibilities. Thus your current solution:

- using the executor inside the `Job` i.e. call `executor.execute()` inside the Job's execute method

can inflict the correct function of the Scheduler itself.

#### Retry controlled from within the job

There might be a couple of ways how to deal with retries in Quartz.
Take a search here in Stackoverflow for [`[quartz-scheduler] retry`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bquartz-scheduler%5D+retry):

- Automatic retry of failed jobs
- Count-based retries, increasing delays between retries, etc.

This question explains some:
[Quartz retry when failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408858/quartz-retry-when-failure)